# can't download python-rtkit using pip

Tags: python, ubuntu, download, pip

Here's my attempt to download python-rtkit using pip:

user@system:~$ pip install python-rtkit

Downloading/unpacking python-rtkit

Could not find anty download that satisfy the requirement python-rtkit

No distribution at all found for python-rtkit

Storing complete log in /home/jgreen/.pip/pip.log

Then in the log file I have this:

---

/usr/bin/pip run on Wed May 29 17:39:36 2013
Downloading/unpacking python-rtkit

Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/: timed out

Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/ when looking for download links for python-rtkit

Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out

Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for python-rtkit

Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/

URLs to search for versions for python-rtkit:

- https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/

  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/

  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/: timed out

  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-rtkit/ when looking for download links for python-rtkit

  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-rtkit

No distributions at all found for python-rtkit

Exception information:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1026, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 171, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)

DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for python-rtkit

The log implies to me that it couldn't find the pypi.python.org/simple page but I can ping pypi.python.org just fine.  Any ideas on what could possibly be the problem here?  Thanks in advance for all help.

EDIT:
Ok, so going around the proxy didn't change anything.  I made progress by doing the following:
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://username:password@proxyip:port"
unset http_proxy
pip install --use-mirrors python-rtkit

That last line looks like it can find the server but can't write because of access restrictions. Then when I ran that line under sudo I got the same error as earlier.

Comment: It installs just fine for me. Can you install other packages through `pip`?

Comment: Are you behind some proxy?

Comment: i managed to get it to try without going through the proxy and it still doesn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: you think at this point maybe it would be better to move this to superuser?  It seems that the focal ponit of my problem is getting less programming focused.

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to fix it by running the code without the sudo as talked about above and then seeing where it didn't have access and using chmod to make everyone have access to that specific directory so that it would work.  A little gimmicky but whatever I'm out of other ideas.